# Delete until whitespace in Emacs

Tags: emacs, whitespace, alphanumeric

Is there an Emacs function to delete (forward or backwards) until the first whitespace?  For example, I have the following line, and the cursor is marked by the caret:

```
someword ?(&)!* morewords
               ^
```

I want to delete the backwards the sequence of non-alphanumeric characters, but not the word `someword`.  Using `backward-delete-word` will wipe out the word as well.  The same is with the cursor before the weird characters and `kill-word`.

Comment: You know, you have the same happening in almost every text area, try the search field here on Stack for instance...

Comment: True, but I don't write thousands of code and prose lines in search fields.

Comment: @Little: Well no, I just wanted to point it out. I think it's an interesting question. But the question is if emacs just doesn't conform to "what everyone else does" and as such doesn't provide a logical `kill-word` function. :)

Comment: @Patrick: Obviously it does, but I want it also to do something else, and Emacs has more options than a text field.

Comment: The best thing about Emacs -- and this is what the IDE-loving Emacs-haters fail to grasp -- is that you can make Emacs work the way you want instead of having to conform to what is available.

Comment: @scottfrazer: Of course you can, you can make create functions with lisp, i.e. do anything. It's like extensions or macros to VS, only easier. I didn't say it was impossible, I was just pointing out ...oh, never mind.

Comment: @Patrick: My comment wasn't directed at you, just making a general observation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any function, but it's easy enough to make one:

```
(defun my-delete-backward-to-ws ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point) (save-excursion (skip-syntax-backward "^ ") (point))))
```

Comment: as of the time I write this comment, that doesn't go to any whitespace, only to a space.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: Hm, works for me.  Tabs and newlines should have whitespace syntax ... I don't know why they wouldn't in some particular mode.

Comment: my mistake. You are correct. I was thinking of regular expressions rather than syntax classes.

Answer (score 20):

emacs has the function `zap-to-char` which will delete everything up to a specific character. So, this won't work for all whitespace but if your specific problem is everything up to a space you can use this function. Give the function a negative argument to zap backwards.

Comment: Bound to `M-z` by default.